# Parsing issue warning with JSON

Tags: c++, json, parsing

I'm trying to read JSON data from a website. I'm using Dev C++ on Windows 10 with a mingw compiler. This is a JSON parser from a tutorial I'm trying to run in a static project:

```
#define CURL_STATICLIB
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

#include "curl.h"
#include "json.h"

namespace
{
    std::size_t callback(
            const char* in,
            std::size_t size,
            std::size_t num,
            std::string* out)
    {
        const std::size_t totalBytes(size * num);
        out->append(in, totalBytes);
        return totalBytes;
    }
}

int main()
{
    const std::string url("http://date.jsontest.com/");

    CURL* curl = curl_easy_init();

    // Set remote URL.
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());

    // Don't bother trying IPv6, which would increase DNS resolution time.
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);

    // Don't wait forever, time out after 10 seconds.
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

    // Follow HTTP redirects if necessary.
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);

    // Response information.
    int httpCode(0);
    // std::unique_ptr<std::string> httpData(new std::string());

    std::stringstream httpData;

    // Hook up data handling function.
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, callback);

    // Hook up data container (will be passed as the last parameter to the
    // callback handling function).  Can be any pointer type, since it will
    // internally be passed as a void pointer.
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &httpData);

    // Run our HTTP GET command, capture the HTTP response code, and clean up.
    curl_easy_perform(curl);
    curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &httpCode);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

    if (httpCode == 200)
    {
        std::cout << "\nGot successful response from " << url << std::endl;

        // Response looks good - done using Curl now.  Try to parse the results
        // and print them out.
        Json::Value jsonData;
        Json::CharReaderBuilder jsonReader;
        std::string errs;

        if (Json::parseFromStream(jsonReader, httpData, &jsonData, &errs))
            // jsonReader.parse(httpData, jsonData))
        {
            std::cout << "Successfully parsed JSON data" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "\nJSON data received:" << std::endl;
            std::cout << jsonData.toStyledString() << std::endl;

            const std::string dateString(jsonData["date"].asString());
            const std::size_t unixTimeMs(
                    jsonData["milliseconds_since_epoch"].asUInt64());
            const std::string timeString(jsonData["time"].asString());

            std::cout << "Natively parsed:" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "\tDate string: " << dateString << std::endl;
            std::cout << "\tUnix timeMs: " << unixTimeMs << std::endl;
            std::cout << "\tTime string: " << timeString << std::endl;
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Could not parse HTTP data as JSON" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "HTTP data was:\n" << httpData.str() << std::endl;
            return 1;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Couldn't GET from " << url << " - exiting" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And this is the error I've been getting:

> [Warning] 'Reader' is deprecated  (declared at
>   C:/Users/me/Downloads/jsoncpp-master/jsoncpp-master/include/json/reader.h:35):
>   | Use CharReader and CharReaderBuilder instead
>   [-Wdeprecated-declarations]

I figured the syntax was older, thus I swapped the object's terms for the recommended ones. Now I'm getting this error: 
This was my corrected block:

```
Json::Value jsonData;
Json::CharReaderBuilder CharReader;

if (CharReader.parse(*httpData, jsonData))
```

And this is the new error:

> error: 'class Json::CharReaderBuilder' has no member named 'parse'
>            if (CharReader.parse(*httpData, jsonData))

---

**The above code corrects this. The particular issue has been corrected**. 
However, due to a library issue, this is my new errors when compiling.

```
g++.exe main.o -o CurlProject1.exe -L"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib" -L"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib" -L"C:/Users/me/Downloads/curl-7.56.1-win64-mingw/lib" -static-libgcc -L"C:/Users/me/Downloads/curl-7.56.1-win64-mingw/lib" ../../Downloads/curl-7.56.1-win64-mingw/lib/libcurl.a ../../Downloads/curl-7.56.1-win64-mingw/lib/libcurl.dll.a

main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x207): undefined reference to `Json::Value::Value(Json::ValueType)'
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x213): undefined reference to `Json::CharReaderBuilder::CharReaderBuilder()'
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x242): undefined reference to `Json::parseFromStream(Json::CharReader::Factory const&, std::istream&, Json::Value*, std::string*)'
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x2a1): undefined reference to `Json::Value::toStyledString() const'
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x2e8): undefined reference to `Json::Value::operator[](char const*)'
```

Comment: out of curiosity, is there any reason you didnt use [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/property_tree.html) property tree json?

Comment: I'm new to parsing json with C++ (i've done it python), and I was told numerous amounts of ways to call data--one of them being boost. Others using curl. I'm just trying to get a functional example to work off of. I'd prefer to stick with this method and not drastically change code until I can understand its proper functionality.

However, If you could incorporate an example into this existing code I wouldn't mind examining it.

Comment: where did you download the header files from?

Comment: curl from here: https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/
json from a stackoverflow depository.

Comment: how about json?

Comment: https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp Are you considering there's something wrong with my library headers?

Comment: I am just wondering how to verify the code without looking at the libraries.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
#include <sstream>


...

    std::stringstream httpData;
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &httpData);

...

        Json::Value jsonData;
        Json::CharReaderBuilder jsonReader;
        std::string errs;
        if (Json::parseFromStream(jsonReader, httpData, &jsonData, &errs))
...

            std::cout << "HTTP data was:\n" << httpData.str() << std::endl;
```

The complete code:

```
#define CURL_STATICLIB
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

#include "curl.h"
#include "json.h"

namespace
{
    std::size_t callback(
            const char* in,
            std::size_t size,
            std::size_t num,
            char* out)
    {
        std::string data(in, (std::size_t) size * num);
        *((std::stringstream*) out) << data;
        return size * num;        
    }
}

int main()
{
    const std::string url("http://date.jsontest.com/");

    CURL* curl = curl_easy_init();

    // Set remote URL.
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());

    // Don't bother trying IPv6, which would increase DNS resolution time.
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);

    // Don't wait forever, time out after 10 seconds.
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

    // Follow HTTP redirects if necessary.
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);

    // Response information.
    int httpCode(0);
    // std::unique_ptr<std::string> httpData(new std::string());

    std::stringstream httpData;

    // Hook up data handling function.
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, callback);

    // Hook up data container (will be passed as the last parameter to the
    // callback handling function).  Can be any pointer type, since it will
    // internally be passed as a void pointer.
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &httpData);

    // Run our HTTP GET command, capture the HTTP response code, and clean up.
    curl_easy_perform(curl);
    curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &httpCode);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

    if (httpCode == 200)
    {
        std::cout << "\nGot successful response from " << url << std::endl;

        // Response looks good - done using Curl now.  Try to parse the results
        // and print them out.
        Json::Value jsonData;
        Json::CharReaderBuilder jsonReader;
        std::string errs;

        if (Json::parseFromStream(jsonReader, httpData, &jsonData, &errs))
            // jsonReader.parse(httpData, jsonData))
        {
            std::cout << "Successfully parsed JSON data" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "\nJSON data received:" << std::endl;
            std::cout << jsonData.toStyledString() << std::endl;

            const std::string dateString(jsonData["date"].asString());
            const std::size_t unixTimeMs(
                    jsonData["milliseconds_since_epoch"].asUInt64());
            const std::string timeString(jsonData["time"].asString());

            std::cout << "Natively parsed:" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "\tDate string: " << dateString << std::endl;
            std::cout << "\tUnix timeMs: " << unixTimeMs << std::endl;
            std::cout << "\tTime string: " << timeString << std::endl;
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Could not parse HTTP data as JSON" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "HTTP data was:\n" << httpData.str() << std::endl;
            return 1;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Couldn't GET from " << url << " - exiting" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Results:

```
Got successful response from http://date.jsontest.com/
Successfully parsed JSON data

JSON data received:
{
    "date" : "11-14-2017",
    "milliseconds_since_epoch" : 1510699420942,
    "time" : "10:43:40 PM"
}

Natively parsed:
    Date string: 11-14-2017
    Unix timeMs: 1510699420942
    Time string: 10:43:40 PM
```

Comment: What line is 
   [code] std::stringstream httpData;
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &httpData); [/code]

Replacing in the code? Or do I just add it after:

CURL* curl = curl_easy_init();

Comment: Also with the JSON initialization, compiler is telling me its an invalid initialization. 
 error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'std::istream& {aka std::basic_istream<char>&}' from expression of type 'std::unique_ptr<std::basic_string<char> >'

Comment: @owen, the completed code I placed here compiles fine for me. Just dont forget to turn on `-std=c++11` switch.

Comment: By "turning on -std=c++11 switch" means using standard c++11 for my IDE?  I usually use c++11

Comment: @Owen, if using `gcc` compiler, use `-std=c++11`. If use `VS` or `codeblocker`, go to the project setting and check `c++11` option.

Comment: I'm using the mingw g++ compiler. My IDE runs in C++11 already.

Comment: I've dealt with the CURL library issue I think. Now, I need to properly link the JSON libraries. I think.
My errors are: 
`main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x207): undefined reference to `Json::Value::Value(Json::ValueType)` Good news is that direct CURL object undefined reference errors aren't showing up anymore, so thats good.

Comment: I'm definitely having library issues. Do you know of a tutorial where I could read clear instructions for linking them? Now my JSON is acting up. (I'll post the error in the original question). If you have a better way of parsing JSOn data from a url, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: I got the program working, but the source code crashes now.

Comment: The source code crashes around line 65
   `curl_easy_perform(curl);
    curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &httpCode);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);`

Comment: It seems the failure is from `callback` function when it calls `append`. Use my updated code where I have fixed `callback`.

Comment: You're a lifesaver man! I've been working on a JSON parser for over a month. Now I can get started. Thanks, I'll study the objects thoroughly.

Comment: Check out this [additional example](https://jsoncpp.docsforge.com/master/readfromstring.cpp/)